# How to call Oracle stored procedure for load Data Grid View

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, datatable

I created a table using this code

```
CREATE TABLE TABLECATEGORY
(
     CATEGORYID NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY KEY,
     CATEGORYNAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE 
)
```

and this stored procedure for select and load to grid

```
create or replace PROCEDURE selectCategory
    (c_catid OUT TABLECATEGORY.CATEGORYID%TYPE,
     c_catname OUT TABLECATEGORY.CATEGORYNAME%TYPE)  
IS
BEGIN
   SELECT CATEGORYID,CATEGORYNAME
   INTO c_catid, c_catname 
   FROM TABLECATEGORY ;
END;
```

I have use this C# code to load data into data grid

```
con.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "selectcategory";

OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

When I execute the program in Visual Studio, I this this error shown in this screenshot:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h66AO.png)

Comment: The stored procedure has two parameters. And you are not passing any parameter from C# while calling the stored procedure. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: would you please correct this procedure,@ChetanRanpariya

Comment: remove `c_catid` and `c_catname` parameters from stored procedure and change query to `SELECT CATEGORYID,CATEGORYNAME FROM TABLECATEGORY ;`.

Comment: Found  the error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object DATABASENAME.SELECTCATEGORY is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored'